# Getting error "Converting circular structure to JSON" while working with express,mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to find tours within a specific distance.here is my code

```
exports.getTourWithin = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { distance, latlng, unit } = req.params;
  const [lat, lng] = latlng.split(',');
  if (!lat || !lng) {
    next(
      new AppError(
        `please provide latitude amd longitude in the form of lat,lng`,
        400
      )
    );
  }
  const radius = unit === 'mi' ? distance / 3963.2 : distance / 6378.1;

  const tours = Tour.find({
    $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius] }
  });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      data: tours
    }
  });
});
```

but i'm getting this error in postman:

```
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle",
    "stack": "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle\n    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)\n    at stringify (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\response.js:1119:12)\n    at ServerResponse.json (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\response.js:260:14)\n    at D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\controllers\\tourControllers.js:190:19\n    at D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\utilis\\catchAsync.js:3:5\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:137:13)\n    at Route.dispatch (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:112:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:281:22\n    at param (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:354:14)\n    at param (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:365:14)\n    at param (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:365:14)\n    at param (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:365:14)\n    at Function.process_params (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:410:3)\n    at next (D:\\Node-Jonas\\Node-Rest-Api\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)"
}
```

how i can solve this issue?Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I came across this exact error. You need to add "await" to your call to the Tours model as you're using async/await. You also need to include the field name you're querying on per @Anatoly's point:

```
const tours = await Tour.find({
    yourfieldname: {
        $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius] }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I forget to put await in front of find() operation of mongo in a controller . It worked for me after adding await in that statement
So it returned promise instead of desired results

for good understanding, read it once
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-db-collection-find-method/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In `tours` you got a cursor not the data themselves.
You should call `toArray` to retrieve the data.

```
const tours = Tour.find({
    $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius] }
  });
res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      data: tours.toArray()
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but after trying your code it's said ""message": "tours.toArray is not a function","

Comment: Hmm. Can you look at `tours` content by setting a breakpoint at `res.status` line?

Comment: i missed to use await before Tour.find({
    $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius] }
  });  after using await now i'm getting different error message ""message": "unknown top level operator: $geoWithin","

Comment: You didn't indicate a field before $geoWithin operator

Comment: Thanks Anatoly.i already fixed that but really thanks for your times and concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I missing **await** in the **async** function by adding await this finding the search id

Comment: This is same as the previous answers, and an answer to a question with an already accepted answer. Please check other answers before answering a question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `await` before the `find()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Async so you have to add `await` in `Find()` function. In my case, the same error was occurred and solved by await.

Answer (score 0):

For me I missing await in the async function

```
// Delete Data 
 app.delete('/todos/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const result =Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.json(result)
 })
```

**Fixed By Add await then it worked fine**

```
// Delete Data 
app.delete('/todos/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
   const result = await Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
   res.json(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`tour.find` will be executed asynchronously so we should handle the requests by then and catch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, in the accepted answer there is `await Tour.find`. It perfectly handles async code

Comment: yes, as the compilation stops until the query gets compiled it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You may miss "await" keyword.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72127878/2227743).